# Program should get a number from user then

Tags: java, numbers, primes, modulo

I read an int **numer** from the user.
I should calculate all numbers which have mod1 until **numer** is reached.
The program should write them  one  by one.

```
public class meraba {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Sayı girin");
    number = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
        if (number == i) {
            for(int d = 0;d<number;d++){

            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I couldn't get it to do that.

I'm looking forward to a correct solution
 in java.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class meraba {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int number;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Sayı girin");
    number = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 1) {
          System.out.println("Mod 1 condition satisfies: " + i);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I hope, I understood your question very well ;)